# General standard SQL equivalent to UNPIVOT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

What is general way for unpivoting a table using only standard SQL?

I'm aware that T-SQL has the UNPIVOT operator and I'm wondering if there is an equivalent in standard SQL (not necessarily an operator but a standard, recommended way for such task without making the code unecessarily complex).

Current answers in StackOverflow refer only to T-SQL.

Comment: To unpivot *n* columns: Either *n* Selects (one per column) plus UNION ALL or a Cross Join to *n* rows (usually numbers from 1 to n) plus a CASE for each column.

Comment: Can you give example data and result -- then we can show you the best way.

Comment: I'm more interested in the general approach to this problem. Any example would work. In practice, I have about 3,000 spreadsheets with a variable number of columns that I will need to Unpivot. I will use Java to capture the columns and create the SQL code on MariaDB. The question here would be how to do a Cartersian Product in the most efficient way, which seems to be the Union All mentioned above.